# How to find what ports are exposed from docker image?

Tags: docker

I have some docker image. In my example it is called `sample_nginx`:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
sample_nginx        latest              4b34f8307839        34 hours ago        231.6 MB
```

I can run it `docker run sample_nginx` and in the colomn "PORTS" I can see what ports are exposed from that image:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
650d7a9fe46e        sample_nginx:latest   "/bin/sh -c 'nginx -   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        80/tcp              sleepy_mclean
```

Is it possible to find out what ports are exposed from the image without running it?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `docker inspect` on an image to find this (and a variety of other interesting things):

```
$ docker inspect redis:latest
```

The above command will give you a significant amount of detail. You can alternately pass a [format argument](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#inspect) to return just what you're looking for, as below.

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{.Config.ExposedPorts}}' redis:latest
map[6379/tcp:map[]]
```